# What is wrong with this makefile and how to fix it?

Tags: makefile

I have got 4 files: pass1.c , pass2.c, main.c and header1.h.

Each of these files, include the file header.h

I wrote the following makefile:

```
assembler: pass1.o pass2.o main.o 
    gcc pass1.o pass2.o -o assembler

pass1.o:     pass1.c
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic pass1.c -o pass1.o

pass2.o:     pass2.c
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic pass2.c -o pass2.o

main.o:    main.c
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic main.c -o main.o
```

When I did make, I got the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In     function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:2: recipe for target 'assembler' failed
make: *** [assembler] Error 1
```

Note that I didn't write a function called 'start'.

What is the problem here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Obviously, there's no function `main` in any of your object files.

Comment: @tofro I do see a main.o file in within my project.

Comment: You don't link to that object file.  Also, you typically want to have the file containing `main` in the beginning of your link line. You might get other undefined symbols if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gcc pass1.o pass2.o -o assembler
```

should be

```
gcc main.o pass1.o pass2.o -o assembler
```

Rename `main.c` to `assembler.c` and your *entire* makefile can be condensed to

```
CFLAGS  := -ansi -Wall -pedantic
objects := assembler.o pass1.o pass2.o
assembler: $(objects)
$(objects): header.h
```

assuming that `cc` on your system is a symlink to `gcc`.